# "Surround selection on typing quote or brace:" not working

Tags: goland

There is something in Goland settings that is annoying me. I have this settings with the option "Surround selection on typing quote or brace"

[image: Goland settings]

So if I am in this state with a selected text:

[image: Initial situation]

This is what happens when I type " ' ":
[image: Result]

The selected text is gone and I have a ' with an underscore.

However with {} is working fine:
[image]

What is wrong in my settings?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

It is a problem related with the keyboard layout. In my particular case I was using "US. International" and caused it to fail. Using "US" layout fixes that bug.

Comment: This is the right answer, thanks from the future @Javier :D